# How to read configurations put it on an initializer files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have placed all of my custom configurations from application.rb to initializers/batch.rb file and the configuration look likes this

```
 Batch.enc_sys = "utf"
```

from a file which I have used in Models directory how do I read the above value? I could not read them like the way I read values which declared in application.rb

Can anyone help?

Comment: How you declared them in application.rb?

Comment: config.enc_sys = "utf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way (RAILS way) would be make a config.yml file within the config directory like this

```
defaults: &defaults
  batch:
   enc_sys: utf8

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

This configuration file gets loaded from a custom initializer in config/initializers:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

You can then get the value like:

```
APP_CONFIG["batch"]['enc_sys']
```

Comment: Can't I have an import like aplication.rb ? from a initializer rather than defining a yaml ?

Comment: It is a standard way of doing it in Rails. There are workarounds but why to take that pain when framework gives you direct way to do it.

Comment: BY the way how do we load the configuration file?

Comment: Its there in the answer. Please vote up my answer if it really helped you.

Comment: Um quite new to rails and what should I include in [RAILS_ENV] and where do I should include APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")[RAILS_ENV]

Comment: You put this line in initializers/batch.rb and remove all other. RAILS_ENV is a constant so keep it like it is.

Comment: Replace it with with Rails.env

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated as of now